# OnInit opening modal dialog twice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net website which takes a login and saves to a class inside a session.  When the session expires (or when I clear it), I need the user to log in again, but preferably without going back to main login page (as the user loses everything they've typed up to that point).

On the master page OnInit, I check to see if the session is null, if so, they're logged out.  I created a jquery modal dialog on my master page which takes in the login information and recreates the session if valid login.

This works, however, the dialog then opens a second time after they've logged in and the dialog has closed (at which point, the session is not null).

I've tried setting a different session value during the login process so it won't open the modal dialog, but it doesn't see it and opens it anyway (and sees the login session has being null even though it isn't.

x'ing out of the dialog, everything is fine.

can someone please tell me where i'm going wrong or how to prevent the dialog from opening twice?

Master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showloginpopup() {
        $("#popuplogin").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            width: 320,
            height: 310,
            modal: true,
            // dialogClass: "no-close", // adding this would remove the x button
            appendTo: "form",
            buttons: {

            }
        });
    };
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upLogin" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="popuplogin" style="display: none;" class="ticker" title="Login">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlWorkArea" runat="server" CssClass="login_workarea_panel" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
                <%-- textboxes and btnLogin for logging in --%>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

btnLogin reads the textboxes and populates my session with user information.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (Classes.LoggedInUser.Current.loggedInUser == null) // This is returning null on 2nd time even though after first time it is set
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Login Popup", "showloginpopup();", true);
        loadData(); // Populate some buttons based on permissions from login
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what I suggest is,you can use another session or querystring,while opening the popup as a flag,once it get open flag it true,so another time when its true,that popup will not get displayed, (NOTE that this is not really good way,because you are creating new session which may take much memory only for this purpose,but I have suggested without considering the matter of memory use. :) )

Comment: I did try this

if (Classes.LoggedInUser.Current.loggedInUser == null && Session["_mylogin_"] == null)

 - then setting the session, and and then resetting to null during login - made no difference :|

  almost as if the dialog had decided to open that 2nd time before the session was set

Comment: Not an issue, did u debug and check what are you getting after login success in  " loggedInUser ",If I am not wrong than " loggedInUser " is constant of some class (It may system security class,do not) ,but what I insist direct check with Session["MyLogin"].Tostring() == NULL && Session["MyLogin"].Tostring() == "" (Its always good to check with blank too.)

Comment: ok, stepping through..
Current.loggedInUser is null, scriptmanager line is run.  It then immediately goes to OnInit again, sees Current.loggedInUser is null and runs scriptmanager line again (which actually opens the dialog)

then the dialog opens

i enter credentials, btnLogin causes a postback (where it'll repopulate Current.loggedInUser) so we get OnInit again where it sees Current.loggedInUser as null (because it isn't set yet until after OnInit)- so runs scriptmanager line again

setting a session after scriptmanager line stops it running on 2nd go [cont.]

Comment: which stops the dialog ever opening.  setting it on the btnLogin doesn't work because OnInit runs BEFORE the btnLogin_Click - so because btnLogin_Click fixes my user session and sets this new session,they are both null at OnInit meaning session is never set and dialog appears twice (dialog opens and user session is set, so x'ing out of dialog still has user session populated). ugh.

Comment: You can use OnLoad(),and there is "IsPostback" property,(IE : check IsPostback==true) so you might get rid out of this.

Comment: Same issue with OnLoad() - and I don't think I can use the postback because I need to log back in whether it is postback or not. (I can't have them leave/reload the page, they need to stay logged in so they don't lose what they've done) - so any submit or page click needs to check for login

Comment: As I can see,there is some Code-side operations,so chances of post-back too...by the way I have done for the day,so might be not available for next few hours and will not able to reply you,I will work over this issue soon,meanwhile if you its resolved by you,so let me know and post your answer,so others can also rid out of this kind of issues.

Comment: thanks for your help - i found a kind of kludgy workaround that i'll post below

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat kludgy workaround, and that is to check my login dialogs username textbox for a value.

If no value, then display the dialog - if there is a value, don't (because the postback from dialog is causing the duplicated dialog).

if anyone has a better answer, please go ahead.